# I'm trying to run a command using WMI

Tags: c#, wmi

This is my code: a button is clicked and the text in a textbox is taken for the remotePC. I can run it locally but when I try to run it remotely it will not work, I think it has something to do with using WMI to run a shared file?

```
public void IPXFER(string RemotePC)
{    
    object[] theProcessToRun = { @"\\network-share\ipxfer\ipxfer.exe -s corp-trend -p 1234 -m 1 -c 12345" };
    ConnectionOptions theConnection = new ConnectionOptions();
    theConnection.Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;
    theConnection.EnablePrivileges = true;
    ManagementScope theScope = new ManagementScope("\\\\" + RemotePC + "\\root\\cimv2", theConnection);
    ManagementClass theClass = new ManagementClass(theScope, new ManagementPath("Win32_Process"), new ObjectGetOptions());
    theClass.InvokeMethod("Create", theProcessToRun);
}
```

Comment: I added file.copy to copy the share file to the remotepc, this works great but when I try to execute the batch file, it does not work. The only thing I can think is that when wmi runs this batch file its in a different session?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using file.copy and then executing the exe with the switches with WMI, that fixed the issue.